# No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString!

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Alguien me puede orientar en este error como verán estoy tratando de insertar pero me sale este error? ya  estuve buscando en foros pero no encuentro solución agradecería mucho si se puede solucionar...

-Esta es la clase conexion

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Productos"].ConnectionString);

        protected SqlConnection GetConnetion()
        {

            return cn;
        }
```

Este el método que me da error
// de la clase Productos

```
 public void D_InsertarProductos(string nombre,string descrip,string marca,float precio, int stock)
       {
           using (var conexion = GetConnetion())
           {
               conexion.Open(); //<-AQUI EL ERROR!!!
               using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
               {
                   cmd.Connection = conexion;
                   cmd.CommandText = "insert into Productos values (@nombre,@descrip,@marca,@precio,@stock)";
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre",nombre);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descrip",descrip);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", marca);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", marca);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   cmd.Parameters.Clear();

               }
           }

       }
```

Lo estoy haciendo en capas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para qué llamar a  `GetConnetion()`. No te hace falta, con instancia una nueva conexión en tu bloque `using` ya lo tendrías.

```
using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Productos"].ConnectionString);
)
           {
               conexion.Open(); //<-AQUI EL ERROR!!!
               using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
               {
                   cmd.Connection = conexion;
                   cmd.CommandText = "insert into Productos values (@nombre,@descrip,@marca,@precio,@stock)";
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre",nombre);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descrip",descrip);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", marca);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", marca);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock);
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   cmd.Parameters.Clear();

               }
           }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apollo te agradesco mi estimado